# Adobe AIR can't show Flash embedded in HTML?

Tags: air

of all three choices (AIR+AJAX, +Flash, and +FLEX) I went on the AJAX route. But it seems that it can't show Flash embedded in HTML (using the traditional OBJECT tag).

Is it by design? or my fault?

Answer (score 1):

i think it's your fault. there are a number of air "web browsers" and they all can display flash just fine.

google for some. i found one [here](http://airbrowser.9t9.us/) and it gives the source code as well

Comment: Those are made with Flex, e.g. the <initalWindow><content> is something.swf, mine is just plain HTML, e.g. the initialWindow is something.html that contains (among other things) a flash banner embedded using <object> tag, but it doesn't show.

Answer (score 1):

I've found the culprit: my window is transparent.
According to [adobe](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7e79.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118676a3e36-7ff9), SWF and PDF won't be displayed if transparency is used.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Ajax but i do know the preferred method to embed flash into html is to use [swfobject](http://blog.deconcept.com/swfobject/). have you tried that yet?